# How to combine into one line in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, iterator, each

The code below works fine. But it seem clunky.

How would you combine the following code into one line?

```
data = Array.new
@results.each{ |result| data.push(result.get_output) }
data.join("\n")
```

Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Are you running out of lines?  I can send you some more if you like... :)

Comment: I thought there must be a better, more eloquent way. Using {}.join

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) the original collection instead of creating a new array first:

```
@results.map(&:get_output).join("\n")
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven’t checked this, but try something like:

```
data = @results.map{ |result| result.get_output }.join("\n")
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, this isn't the same as `data` never contained the `join`ed array, just the array and had `join` called on it. But that may just be me being pedantic.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall yep, you’re right. I was assuming this intention as the last line isn’t mutating anything, so it must be at the end of a method and returning that anyway.

Comment: @EdwardOcampo-Gooding Yes, the last line isn't mutating anything. This is the whole method. I should have put `def` and `end` in the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = @results.collect(&:get_output).join("\")
```

1. Use `collect` (or map) to create an array
2. (&:get_output), is equivalent to `collect{|result| result.get_output}
3. chain join to the end of the results to format it

If you get empty lines, add `compact` before join.  This helps clean up the results.